# Flash Interface in Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, flash

is it possible to create an application with flash interface in Vb?
I'm using visual basic 2008.thanks.

Comment: What is the reason for using Flash?  Is this a requirement?  Or are you already comfortable using Flash?  Does Flash give you some feature that you want to use that some other technology (Silverlight, WPF) doesn't give you?

Comment: i just want my form design stunning with the use of flash..what else should i use in order to have a great design in my form?

Comment: If this is to run on Windows, you could use WPF.  It would give you many features.  If you need to run it on the web or on both the web or Windows, then you can use Silverlight, which is a subset of WPF.  I don't know if there is a way to use Flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that a decade ago in VB6.  Back then, there was an SWF player ActiveX that could be added to a form...  I think the ActiveX DLL was included in that standard Flash plugin for IE and the only thing I had to do is to add a reference to that DLL.

Back then, it was distributed by Macromedia... I'm not sure if it's still possible since Adobe is the distributor.

Sorry if I don't have any recent informations about this :(